# Flink: Memory Usage

Tags: apache-flink

I am measuring memory usage for an application (WordCount) in Flink with `ps -p TaskManagerPID -o rss`. However the results don’t make any sense. Because for every amount of data (1MB, 10MB, 100MB, 1GB, 10GB) there is the same amount of memory used. For 10GB data the result of the measurement is even less than 10GB. Is TaskManager the wrong process for measuring memory usage? Which process of the Flink Process Model is responsible for memory allocation?

Comment: It's the right process to monitor. The resource consumption strongly depends on your job (e.g. size if intermediate data, materialization necessary, number of Taskmanagers among which to distribute the data). Maybe you could give a little bit more context about the test setup and the test job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flink features two processing modes, stream and batch processing.

**Stream Processing**:

In stream processing, Flink uses pluggable state backends to maintain the state of an applications. In Flink version 1.5.0, there are two types of state backends. 1) backends (`FsStateBackend` and `MemoryStateBackend`) that store the application state on the heap of the worker (TaskManager) JVM process and 2) the `RocksDBStateBackend` that stores the state in RocksDB on disk. In both cases, you can monitor the memory consumption using regular JVM memory monitoring tools. However, for the `RocksDBStateBackend` most of the state will be stored on disk.

**Batch Processing**

The internal processing algorithms (sorting, hash tables) of the batch processing operators work with managed memory that is (typically) pre-allocated when a worker processes (TaskManager) starts and never returned. Flink assigns this managed memory to its algorithms and the algorithms spill to disk if the amount of data exceeds their memory budget. Since all memory is pre-allocated and internally managed by Flink, it is not possible to measure the actual memory consumption.

Comment: Thank your for your quick reply. Could you recommend a link or literature about Flinks memory management?

Comment: There are two blog posts about memory management: [(1)](http://flink.apache.org/news/2015/05/11/Juggling-with-Bits-and-Bytes.html), [(2)](http://flink.apache.org/news/2015/09/16/off-heap-memory.html). Not sure if there is something about the internal memory management (assigning memory to operators).

Comment: If that's the case then does Flink provide a way to estimate/measure the amount of memory consumed?

Comment: No, that's not possible yet. The community is working on improving monitoring though.

Comment: Any updates about the memory usage monitoring since then? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer and described the situation for Flink's stream and batch processing modes.